# Redundant way of getting multiple $_POST records?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**EDIT :** I might just make it a more '*step-by-step*' process i.e.

[image]

Seeing as it feels more user-friendly & it's only for <5 images. I have read & appreciate all of the help that I have received so far.

---

I'm fairly new to PHP & I'm building a basic PHP image editor which may allow multiple image data auditing which is then inserted into a MySQL database. **A limit of 5 images may be uploaded at a time for this system** (implying that there will only be a low amount of records to play with), but I'll get to that further down.

GUI:

[image]

Some of the data columns used:

- image id
- caption
- description
- published
- imageposition
- delete button

All images are echo'd in a while loop by a previous 'SELECT *' result set. Each image will have the 'image id' echo'd inside each input **name**, so output will be for example:

caption-2, description-2, published-2, imageposition-2, caption-3, description-3

Also, the data values from the previous resultset are echo'd into the **input** value, allowing the client to edit the current data that exists in the database. There is only one submit button.

**My question:**

I want to be able to post all of the modified image(s) data to a processor.php form which will then allow me to insert it as an INSERT sql string into the MySQL images table. I need the PHP to be dynamic incase:

- images are deleted (image id)
- new images are uploaded (image id)

If there is an easier way of doing any of the above, I am welcome to new ideas/opinions. Sorry in advance for my poor understanding of PHP.

Comment: Is there any option for add new image in that page ? Or it just edit title/description and delete photo ?

Comment: Yeah, user may add images to MySQL DB (in conjunction with [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com)/[Uploadifive](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/implementing-uploadifive/))

Edit images (edit all image data/delete button)will bring up what is shown in the image in my original post.

I want each delete button to link with the corresponding image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the records easily :

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post">
<?php
foreach ($images as $img) { // assuming $images is the result set of your sql query
?>
  <input type="text" name="name<?php $img['image_id'];?>" value="<?php $img['caption'];?>">
  <input type="text" name="desc<?php $img['image_id'];?>" value="<?php $img['description'];?>">
...
<a href="http://yoursiteurl/deleteimg.php?id=<?php $img['image_id']?>">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

In deleteimg.php :

```
<?php
$del = $_POST[id];
$query = $msqli->prepare("DELETE FROM imagetablename WHERE image_id=?");
$query->bind_param( 's',  $del );
$query->;execute();
?>
```

Updating and adding new rows may involve javascript, and much more harder.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get result from 'select *' statement you do foreach

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
?>
   <img src="imagesrc">
   <input type="text" name="title_<?php echo $image['image_id'] ; ?>" value="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="desc_<?php echo $image['image_id'] ; ?>" value="<?php echo $image['description']; ?>">
   <input type="button" onclick="markDeleted('<?php echo $image['image_id'] ; ?>')">
<?php } ?>
```

.....

Once you receive the post value you can explode with "_" and you will get the Primary key and you can update the image table with image ID.

In the javascript function `markDeleted` you can set the primary key in some hidden field and sent to process.php.

Add it like comma separated 1,2,3 like this (Split by comma in action page)

```
function markDeleted (imageId) 
{
    document.getElementById('deleted_image_ids').value = imageId + ","
}
```